# Not able to access google chrome image in docker container

Tags: google-chrome

`   I am trying to download a google chrome image in a Docker build script. My build script downloads the chrome image from http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/ and then builds and creates a docker image. This used to work till a few days back. Once the build script started failing, I debugged it and found that http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/ is no more accessible. Below is the snippet of my repo file followed by error logs.

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub

The above url is throwing a 404 error

Error Logs
```

---

```
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:18 Public key for google-chrome-stable-114.0.5735.198-1.x86_64.rpm is not installed
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:18 [91mwarning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/google-chrome/packages/google-chrome-stable-114.0.5735.198-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID a3b88b8b: NOKEY
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:18 [0m--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:18 Total 2.3 MB/s | 132 MB 00:58
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:18 Retrieving key from https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19 [91mImporting GPG key 0x7FAC5991:
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19 Userid : "Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster>"
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19 Fingerprint: 4cca 1eaf 950c ee4a b839 76dc a040 830f 7fac 5991
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19 From : https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19 [0m[91mImporting GPG key 0xD38B4796:
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19 Userid : "Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster>"
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19 Fingerprint: eb4c 1bfd 4f04 2f6d ddcc ec91 7721 f63b d38b 4796
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19 From : https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19 [0m[91m
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19 Public key for google-chrome-stable-114.0.5735.198-1.x86_64.rpm is not installed
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19 Failing package is: google-chrome-stable-114.0.5735.198-1.x86_64
build 10-Jul-2023 22:22:19 GPG Keys are configured as: https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

Is there a workaround while this gets sorted out?`

Comment: I have got the work around for this problem and it is working as expected. I just disabled the public key and it is working.                                                                  
**enabled=1**
**gpgcheck=0**